# Display DB2 time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, db2

I am inserting the time values as

```
<?php $time = date("H").date("i").date("s"); ?>
```

in DB2 database field, that has the datatype as `6 S` (Length=6, Type=Signed). So for the time of 6:54 PM, i see that the value is stored as some numeric figure, like: `185,414`.

I want to display back the original value in php.

How do i correctly parse the numeric time value and show that in php ?

Comment: is that db2 field an int? you'd have to treat it as a string when it comes back out and yank it apart into 3 sets of 2 characters.

Comment: The digits() function will convert a number to character without a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i went nuts figuring out the solution, which is rather as simple as removing the commas from the string, and formatting it to display like: **hh:mm:ss**